# Can not get all properties for a DBpedia class

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I use Sparql to get all property for a [specific class](http://dbpedia.org/page/Thin-film-transistor_liquid-crystal_display) with this code.

```
PREFIX db: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX prop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX onto: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
select ?property ?value 
where { db:Thin-film-transistor_liquid-crystal_display ?property ?value . }
```

However, the output result is missing some properties as:

```
is dbpprop:display of   dbpedia:IPhone_4S
                        dbpedia:IPhone_5S
is dbpprop:industry of  dbpedia:InnoLux_Corporation
is dbpprop:paneltype of dbpedia:Dell_monitors
is dbpprop:products of  dbpedia:Zalman
```

How can I get those properties?

Comment: It's not a class but a resource/instance/individual. A class is usually defined as a set of instances/&individuals/resources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The properties that you have mentioned have one important bit in common, "OF". This means that the item you are looking for is the "object" and not the "subject" and you are searching for the "objects". Therefore, if you swap your subject and object in the query, you will find them:

```
PREFIX db: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX prop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX onto: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
select ?property ?value 
where { 
    ?value ?property db:Thin-film-transistor_liquid-crystal_display. 
}
```

So, if you want to get everything out, one way is to a union:

```
PREFIX db: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX prop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX onto: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
select ?property ?value 
where { 
{
   db:Thin-film-transistor_liquid-crystal_display ?property ?value. 
}
union{
    ?value ?property db:Thin-film-transistor_liquid-crystal_display. 
}
}
```

Comment: I think it would be also useful to somehow indicate whether the item is the subject or the object.